# Change scope line color IDEA

Tags: jetbrains-ide, appearance, goland

I want to change color of the line which is located between row numbers and "folding line" (dark yellow on screenshot).
Is there any way for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change it in the settings: `Preferences / Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Code | Matched brace`. However, the background of the matched brackets will also change.